# How I can display automatic current date and time in my card or recycler view?

Tags: java, android

What should I do to avoid redundancy in date and time?
i am using Firebase Database in that am not passing date and time it is automatically adding date and time in card

Below is my adapter class

```
public class Adapter extends FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<member, Adapter.myViewHolder> {


public Adapter(@NonNull FirebaseRecyclerOptions<member> options) {


    super(options);

}

@Override
protected void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull Adapter.myViewHolder holder, int position, @NonNull 
member model) {

    holder.mheadView.setText(model.getTitle());
    holder.mdesView.setText(model.getDescription());
    
 Glide.with(holder.imageView.getContext()).load(model.getImageuri()).into(holder.imageView);

    holder.imageView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            AppCompatActivity activity = (AppCompatActivity) v.getContext();
            
 activity.getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.fragment_container_view, 
  new DetailsFragment(model.getTitle(), model.getImageuri())).addToBackStack(null).commit();
        }
    });


    String date = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MMM-yyy", Locale.getDefault()).format(new Date());
    holder.Date.setText(date);

    String time = "";
    if (model.time == null) {
        time = new SimpleDateFormat("hh:mm:a", Locale.getDefault()).format(new Date());
        holder.Time.setText(time);

    }
 //    else {
//         holder.Time.setText(time);
//            }
    //  holder.Time.setText(time);
    


@NonNull
@Override
public myViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.cardlayout, parent, 
 false);


    return new myViewHolder(view);

}

public static class myViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{
    ImageView imageView;
    TextView mheadView;
    TextView mdesView;

    TextView Date;
    TextView Time;

    ImageView edit,delete;

    public myViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
   
        Date=itemView.findViewById(R.id.date);
        Time=itemView.findViewById(R.id.time);
 
    }
   }
  }
```

Here is my member class

```
 public class member  {
  String description, title, imageuri,time;


public member(){

}


public member(String description, String title, String imageuri,String time) {
    this.description = description;
    this.title = title;
    this.imageuri = imageuri;
    this.time=time;
}

public String getTime() {
    return time;
}

public void setTime(String time) {
    this.time = time;
}

public String getDescription() {
    return description;
}

public void setDescription(String description) {
    this.description = description;
}

public String getTitle() {
    return title;
}

public void setTitle(String title) {
    this.title = title;
}

public String getImageuri() {
    return imageuri;
}
public void setImageuri(String imageuri) {
    this.imageuri = imageuri;
 }
}
```

So in below image same date and time is showing repeatedly
I want different date and time for each card.

I am new in Android trying to learn.

Answer (score 0):

you can use this code as your adapter and set values of date and time by getting values from this arraylist

```
ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> dateTimeArrayList;
public Adapter(@NonNull FirebaseRecyclerOptions<member> options) {
super(options);
 dateTimeArrayList = new ArrayList();
member m = options.getMember();
for(int i=0;i<m.size();i++){
HashMap<String, String> dateTimeHashMap = new HashMap<String, String>();
String date = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MMM-yyy", Locale.getDefault()).format(new 
Date());
String  time = new SimpleDateFormat("hh:mm:a", Locale.getDefault()).format(new 
Date());
dateTimeHashMap.put("date", date);
dateTimeHashMap.put("time", time);
dateTimeArrayList.add(dateTimeHashMap);
```

}}

Answer (score -1):

I think it's because of recyclerview recycle it so I think you can add time of each card to a global array list for your adapter and assign from each position to its relevant card

Answer (score -1):

You can add time in separate Arraylist and pass it to the Constructor of the Adapter. Arraylist size should be equal to your model member size so it will return time according to the position

Comment: can you give me a code hint so I can achieve my task it will be a great help and thanks in advanced

Comment: Please share the code which you are using to add data in the Member Model. I will let you know how to add the code

Comment: only that much code is there  witch I have ask